# How to call a method of another class using codemodel

Tags: java, sun-codemodel

I have a java class say Class A with some methods already present, I am generating a class using code model say `classB` and while generating using code model I am trying to call one the method of that `classA`.

i tried below

```
method
    .body()
    .invoke(JExpr.ref(helper), "display")
    .arg("hello");
```

but it is not working, I will really appreciate if someone knows how to do the same

I want to generate a method like:

```
public void method() { 
    Helper helper = new Helper(); 
    helper.display("hello") 
}
```

I am also interested in how I can generate the following method:

```
@Test 
public void method() { 
    Assert.fail("message") 

}
```

Comment: Explain "it is not working"?

Comment: Please explain what you want to be generated at the end.

Comment: I am getting compilation error, i checked  a lot of forums but didn't get any example to do , i got one where for a list a method is getting called thats why i tried same , but for me its giving compilation issue

Comment: i just want to a create a class with one method with bdy say someObject.disapy("hello")

Comment: Which compilation issue?

Comment: compilation issue : JExpr is not applicable for argumets(helper)

Comment: OK, and what gets generated?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174020/discussion-between-lexicore-and-monis-majeed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with:

```
public void method() { 
    Helper helper = new Helper(); 
    helper.display("hello") 
}
```

Assuming you already have a `JMethod method`, you first need to create a `helper` instance:

```
JVar helper = method
    .body()
    .decl(
        codeModel.ref(Helper.class),
        "helper",
        JExpr._new(codeModel.ref(Helper.class)));
```

Then just invoke the desired method on it:

```
method
    .body()
    .invoke(helper, "display")
    .arg("hello");
```

No this one:

```
@Test
public void method() { 
    Assert.fail("message") 
}
```

It's even easier, you only have to do a static invocation. Something along the lines:

```
method
    .body()
    .staticInvoke(codeModel.ref(Assert.class))
    .arg("message");
```

If you're interested in the annotation:

```
method
    .annotate(Test.class);
```

Note that in the invocations above I could pass strings to the `arg` method directly (`arg("message")`). This is just a convenience method for strings. If you want to use other types like primitve types, you will need to do something like `JExpr.lit(12.34)`.